# Read data from varying positions in a text file

Tags: c#

I am trying to get some data (member name) from two different text files.

### Example Text File 1

```
 aaaaaaaaaaa

 bbbbbbbbbbb

 Member: David

 ccccccccccc

 ddddddddddd
```

### Example Text File 2

```
  aaaaaaaaaaa

  Member:

  David

  BBB BBB BBB
```

In both cases, I want to use the same C# code to read the name DAVID. The problem I'm having is that in the second file, the name is on a different line.

This is my current code, and I need to have one solution for both files.

```
        System.IO.StreamReader file =new System.IO.StreamReader(@"Path");
             string line;
       List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
                if(line.ToUpper().Contains("MEMBER"))
            {                  

                    lines.Add(line);


            }
        }
            foreach (var l in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l); //Member: David
        }
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: You might be better off posting this on codereview

Comment: Actually, I would like to get the name of the member from different text files

Comment: @Bhargav So what is the problem with your current approach? Describe why your solution isn't working, and we can try to help you.

Comment: @john with my approach, I can only access name in the  text file1

Comment: @Bhargav Oh, because it's on the next line? Flag a boolean and read the next line for the name then.

Comment: @jhon I have to access the name in the textfile2 
with the same approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use regex...

```
var name = Regex.Match(File.ReadAllText(filename), @"Member:[ \t\r\n]+(.+?)\r?\n")
           .Groups[1].Value;
```